# Get Absolute URL of an Action (not in view) - NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, url-routing

I have searched for this question a lot and they all seem to have the same answer and seem to pertain to be called by a view instead of a controller.

I have tried to implement the answer but I am getting a `NullReferenceException` on this part `url.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Scheme;`

I have referenced `System.Web.Mvc;` but I am still unable to call `Url.Action`. Instead I had to create a new object of `UrlHelper` and then call the `Action` method. I am unsure if this is the cause of my problem or not.

My code is as follows:

```
    public static class EmailHelper
            {

             public static string AbsoluteAction(this UrlHelper url, string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues = null)
                {
                    // Throws NullReferenceException
                    string scheme = url.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Scheme;

                    return url.Action(actionName, controllerName, routeValues, scheme);
                }

             public static async Task SendReset(string emailAddress)
                {
                    MailDefinition md = new MailDefinition()
                    {
                        IsBodyHtml = true,
                        Subject = "Password Reset",
                        BodyFileName = "~/Templates/ResetConfirm.html",
                    };


                    UrlHelper helper = new UrlHelper();
                    string url = helper.AbsoluteAction("Login", "Account");

                    ListDictionary replacements = new ListDictionary();
                    replacements.Add("{{LoginUrl}}", url);

                    MailMessage msg = md.CreateMailMessage(emailAddress, replacements, new System.Web.UI.Control());
                    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();

                    await client.SendMailAsync(msg);
                }
            }
```

**Edit**

I am calling `SendReset` from the `AccountController`'s `ResetPassword` post action

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> ResetPassword(ResetPasswordViewModel model)
    {
        // some code here...


       var result = await UserManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user.Id, model.Code, model.Password);
       if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                // Email confirmation of password reset
                await EmailHelper.SendReset(model.Email);

                return RedirectToAction("ResetPasswordConfirmation", "Account");
            }
```

Comment: you can't just new up a `UrlHelper` and expect it to work the same way as in a view. Like you said, you will get nullrefs on things like the `HttpContext` - what is value of an `HttpContext` in a static reference frame? There is none, an `HttpContext` only exists while a request/response cycle is happening. If you want to call `SendReset`, you should provide a `UrlHelper` from a view or from an instance of a controller where it has been initialized by the MVC framework.

Comment: can you should the code you're calling `SendReset` from? We could help you find a better way to get a `UrlHelper` object to provide it

Comment: @DLeh i've edited my post to contain the code from where `SendReset` is being called. Do I have to pass the URL of the login page as a parameter in `SendReset`? It seems to be unnecessary because the parameter will always be the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UrlHelper` property `Url` is also accessible in Controllers, so  provide that instance to your method to get access to a `UrlHelper`:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ResetPassword(ResetPasswordViewModel model)
{
    // some code here...
    await EmailHelper.SendReset(Url, model.Email);
    //...
}


public static class EmailHelper
{
    public static async Task SendReset(UrlHelper urlHelper, string emailAddress)
    {
        //...
        string url = urlHelper.AbsoluteAction("Login", "Account");
    }
}
```